# Simulate mouse click in background window

Tags: c++, winapi, input

I'm trying to use `SendMessage` to post mouse clicks to a background window (Chrome), which works fine, but brings the window to front after every click. Is there any way to avoid that?

Before anyone says this is a duplicate question, please make sure that the other topic actually mentions not activating the target window, because I couldn't find any.

**Update:** aha, hiding the window does the trick, almost. It receives simulated mouse/keyboard events as intended, and doesn't show up on screen. However, I can just barely use my own mouse to navigate around the computer, and keyboard input is completely disrupted.

So my question is, how does sending messages to a window affect other applications? Since I'm not actually simulating mouse/keyboard events, shouldn't the other windows be completely oblivious to this?
Is it possibly related to the window calling `SetCapture` when it receives `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`? And how would I avoid that, other than hooking the API call (which would be very, very ugly for such a small task)?

Comment: Why do you want to send clicks to Chrome anyway? If this works as you described, it seems like good security feature to me.

Comment: Are you writing a Clicker Heroes bot? :P

Answer (score 0):

The default handling provided by the system (via `DefWindowProc`) causes windows to come to the front (when clicked on) as a response to the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message, not `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.

The fact that Chrome comes to the front in response to `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` suggests that it's something Chrome is specifically doing, rather than default system behaviour that you might be able to prevent in some way.

The source code to Chrome is available; I suggest you have a look at it and see if it is indeed something Chrome is doing itself. If so, the only practical way you would be able to prevent it (short of compiling your own version of Chrome) is to inject code into Chrome's process and sub-class its main window procedure.

Comment: Actually, it is a Flash app I'm trying to click on, not sure if Chrome decides what happens with mouse clicks in this case. But judging by its behaviour, I'm almost certain that it calls `SetCapture`. I'll try hijacking that function and seeing if it helps.

Comment: @riv The mouse-click has to go through Chrome in order to arrive in your Flash application. I would guess that Chrome thinks: If someone messes with your browser, you probably want to be aware of it. I'd consider that a big security feature.